# android studio 2.2 how to apply dagger2 without android-apt plugin

Tags: android, android-studio

my project build.gradle

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
     jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
    classpath 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}
allprojects {
     repositories {
        jcenter()
     }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
     delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

my module build.gradle

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion '24.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.aber.app.acgtalk"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    jackOptions {
        enabled true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

ext {
supportLibVersion = '24.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    debugAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    provided  'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:support-annotations:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile "com.android.support:preference-v14:${supportLibVersion}";
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.2.0';
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
}
```

what's wrong with this,how to using the annotationProcessor function within the Android studio 2.2 ，how to conifg the dagger2 annotation processor correctly?

[new Jack annotations processors](http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, with android gradle plugin 2.2.0 release, the `android-apt` plugin is no longer needed for annotation processing. The `apt` function was included in the latest android gradle plugin. It's called `annotationProcessor` now which was what you had in your build script. However, there were a few misconfigured stuff in the script.

First of all, the dagger compiler should not be added to classpath. So remove this line: `classpath 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'`.

And you are using android gradle plugin version `alpha3`. Try to use the latest version, so change to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'`.

The dependency declaration block looks legit. So try to make the above changes to see if it would work.

Answer (score -1):

You're incorretly insert plugin classpath. Remove the following line in your project build:

```
classpath 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
```

and insert:

```
classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
```

Then in your module build.gradle, add the following code after apply plugin android application:

```
// add after applying plugin: 'com.android.application'  
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
```

Add the following line to your dependencies:

```
// apt command comes from the android-apt plugin
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

For more information read here:
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Dependency-Injection-with-Dagger-2

and for sample project, visit here:
https://github.com/spirosoik/AndroidArchitecturePadawans

Comment: there is a Jack will automatically apply annotations processors in your classpath. To use an annotation processor at compile-time without bundling it in your apk, use the new annotationProcessor dependency scope:

Enable Jack Annotation Processing

Comment: I don't get what you've meant :(. Imho, android apt plugin will not including the annotation artifact in apk. https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt

Comment: there is a new Jack compiler , it's new feature is : To use an annotation processor at compile-time without bundling it in your apk, use the new annotationProcessor dependency scope , like this : annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'  put this in dependencies of module. see http://android-developers.blogspot.jp/2016/05/android-studio-22-preview-new-ui.html

Comment: owwh... My first time hear it here. Thank you for the info ;)

Comment: As of android gradle plugin 2.2.0 it is now possible to use annotation processors without any additional plugins. The creator `android-apt` is even recommending the migration.

See link: https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/wiki/Migration