# Can't see generated classes by using annotationProcessor and androidTestAnnotationProcessor

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, apt

By [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416573/2425851)

> The apt function was included in the latest android gradle plugin.
>   It's called annotationProcessor

But I cant see generated dagger classes by using `annotationProcessor` and `androidTestAnnotationProcessor`
here is my gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

....
configurations.all {
resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.0.1'
}

dependencies {

    // Dagger
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    androidTestAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'


}

....
```

main gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.3.0-beta4'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.2.0"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

**Why "Gradle build" doesn't generate classes?**

Comment: I don't know dagger but generally have you looked in build/generated-sources? It should be somewhere in there if he generated them successfully. If so you can add them to the sourceSet.